# Is it a good practice to do frequently commits for insert to database in java code?

Tags: java, excel, oracle, optimization, commit

My java code reads the excel file and writes (insert) data from it to oracle database.

For example, I need to read some similar cells in 2000 rows of excel file, my code reads it, insert to database and after do commit.

The first approximately 1000 rows inserts very fast, but another 1000 rows inserts very long.

Possibly reason in the lack of memory.

So, I think to do frequently commits while data is loading to database (e.g. do commit after every 50 rows read).

Is it good practice to do it or there are other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you think memory is a problem?  Modern databases can easily insert thousands of records per second without breaking sweat.  I'm afraid the bottleneck is way more likely to be your code.  Oracle has built-in utilities for loading data from CSV files.  Have you considered using  SQL Loader or an external table?

Comment: Go read [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022).  The answer is, no.  If you have a memory leak in your app, find it and take corrective action.

Comment: @APC - thanks, I just don't know what else could be the cause, because the first row is inserted for a second, but later a minutes. My application should do this job, I am using apache poi for read excel file and PreparedStatement to write data to database. Probably you are right and the problem in reading excel and not in inserting data into the database.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - thanks, I realized that frequent commits is bad

Answer (score 4):

Commits are for ***atomic*** operations in the database. You don't just throw them around because you feel like it. Each transaction is generally (depending on isolation level, but assuming serial isolation) a distinct, all-or-nothing operation.

If you don't know what is causing database transaction to take "long time", you should read the logs or talk to someone that knows how to diagnose the cause of the "slowdown" and remedies it. Most likely reason is bad configuration.

The bottom line is, people have transactions that insert 100,000 or even millions of rows as a single transaction without causing issues. And generally, it is better not to commit often for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Databases always have to be consistent, i.e. **only commit, if your data is consistent, even if your program crashes afterwards**.

(If you don't need that consistency, then why do you use a DB?)

PS: You won't go out of memory that fast.

Comment: thanks, but sorry, I don't fully understand what you meant,  what means "data are consistent"?

Comment: He means that if related data is to be inserted into tables T1, T2, and T3, don't perform a commit until all the related data has been inserted; in other words, don't insert the T1 data and commit, followed by the T2 data and another commit, followed by the T3 data and another commit. Best of luck.

Comment: Or more to your case: Is it OK in case of a crash to end up with half the excel sheet written? If not, then you shouldn't commit. Your 2000 rows is about nothing, look at the DB settings and logs and possibly increase memory. The slowdown may also come from data being physically written or transferred when a buffer fills and then the initial large speed is just an illusion.

Comment: @maaartinus - thanks, in my case it doesn't matter to writte all file (but importantly, in the end, the user needs to know about the failure), but on the advices in this thread I must seek the cause elsewhere and it right